# JPA one-to-one relation not updated to A when saving B

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, entity

I have two entities with one-to-one -relation

```
// simplified pseudocode

public class EntityA {
    @OneToOne EntityB entityB;
}

public class EntityB {
    @OneToOne EntityA entityA;
}
```

Failing example

```
bRepository.saveAndFlush(EntityB.builder().entityA(entityA).build());

... transaction continues

// Fails, entity B is null
assertThat(aRepository.getById(entityA.getId()).getEntityB()).isNotNull();
```

Working example

```
entityA.setEntityB(bRepository.saveAndFlush(EntityB.builder().entityA(entityA).build()));
aRepository.saveAndFlush(entityA);

... transaction continues

// Succeeds, entity B is set
assertThat(aRepository.getById(entityA.getId()).getEntityB()).isNotNull();
```

My question is, why aRepository doesn't see the updated relation in first example? Saving entityA too seems redundant boilerplate to me, but is necessary to pick up the changed relation.

Comment: Why would you expect A to have a B reference if you didn't set it? Your pseudocode doesn't show if you set the A->B reference to be some way bidirectional with the B->A reference or if they are completely independent (and so A has a FK to B in the A table). JPA also has 1st and 2nd levels of caching, so it is best practice to always keep bidirectional relationships in synch with what is in the database, even if it isn't strictly required to force the changes to be persisted there.